# Can one characterise a global field geometrically?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

A global field is either a

1. a finite extension of the rationals
2. a finite extensions of $F_q(t)$

Alternatively, the second is the function field of an algebraic curve over a finite field.

Is there a geometric equivalent to first that is parallel to this?

Comment: I guess the corresponding object to the curve is Spec of the ring of integers of the number field; that's a finite cover of Spec of the integers, just like an algebraic curve is a finite cover of the affine line Spec $F_q[t]$.

Comment: For symmetry, you could think of 1) as the function field of a curve over $\mathbb{F}_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the function field of an integral scheme of finite type and integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Great, thanks; I'm not really familiar with scheme language - how does put the second possibility in that language; presumably its a function field of a not neccessarily integral scheme of finite type  and integral over $F_q(t)$?